# Determine if $ϕ$ has a finite and infinite model or not.

Tags: logic, proof-writing, relations, model-theory

> Let $\sigma = \{E\}$ be a signature with a two-digit relation symbol
> $E$. Determine for the following $FO-[\sigma]$ formula, whether it has
> a finite model and whether it has an infinite model.
>
> $$ϕ := ∀x∃y(E(x, y) ∧ ∀z(z \neq y → ¬E(x, z))) ∧ ∀x∀y∀z(E(x, z) ∧ E(y,
> > z) → x = y) ∧ ∃x∀y¬E(y, x)$$

I am quite frankly lost and not sure what to do here. I know that if $ϕ$ has an arbitrarily large number of finite model, then it has an infinite model. So first I need to determine if $ϕ$ has a model - which would imply that $ϕ$ has a finite model. Then I have to determine if $ϕ$ has an arbitrarily large number of finite models - which would imply that $ϕ$ has an infinite model. But that is where I am not sure what to do. How can I show that $ϕ$ has a model and subsequently that it has an arbitrarily large number of models?

Comment: Already seen sometime ago: $z6=y$ ????

Comment: Sorry it's a typo. Do you have a link to the post? And I'm not sure why it's not letting me save the edit. It should be a $\neq$

Comment: Why not fix it?

Comment: Is $E(y,\gt z)$ a typo for $E(y,z)$?

Comment: The first thing to do is try to figure out what that formula says "in human language". Fortunatele it has a simple meaning: it says that $E$ is a mapping of the universe into itself which is injective but not surjective. Plainly, then, it has no finite models, but it has infinite models.

Comment: This is the third time I've seen this question posted recently, and the last two times even had the same typo of $6=$ for $\neq$. The previous versions seem to have been deleted. Assuming it is the same person posing the question each time, please do not create multiple accounts, and please please do not delete and then repost the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

First, a correction: Having a model does not imply having a finite model. There are formulas having only infinite models (try describing how $<$ works on $\mathbb{N}$).

Then, while it is true that having finite models of arbitrarily large cardinalities implies having an infinite model, this is very rarely the way to go to prove that a concretely given formula has an infinite model.

The most basic way to prove that a formula has a finite/infinite model is to just exhibit one. So have a look at what your formula says, and try to construct a model. You can assume without limitation of generality that the underlying set is either $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ or $\mathbb{N}$. Then you only need to say how $E$ works.

If you get stuck trying to built a finite model, turn the obstacle you keep running into into a proof that any model has to be infinite.

If you get stuck trying to built an infinite model, then it may help finding out the maximal size of a finite model, and to argue that no larger models can exist.